# Can't change status bar colour to translucent black

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-statusbar

I'm trying to change the status bar colour to translucent black (android 7.0) but all I get is a grey status bar. Whenever I try to set the status bar to something transparent or translucent, I get this grey colour. But solid colours work fine.
I'm using a collapsing toolbar layout, I know I can use statusBarScrim, but this feature too is not working, I can't figure out why.

Output:[image]

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#d8000000"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_artistSong"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarSize="10dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="#b2000000"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/parallaxImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed" />



            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                >


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backToArtist"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    />


            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:background="#b2000000"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backToArtist2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/parallaxText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="60dp"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:text="Hello"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_below="@+id/parallaxText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                  >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/NumAlbums"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:paddingLeft="60dp"
                        android:text="@string/albums"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/NumTracks"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/tracks"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:paddingLeft="100dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>






        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>




    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Styles:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#b2000000</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>


</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

Tried using these too:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    Window window = getWindow();
                    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
                     window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.translucent_black2));
                }
```

Comment: Could you also post the colour which you are trying to set along with the output which you are getting?

Comment: The color I'm trying to put is "#b2000000" and output is grey.

Comment: Hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/8745264/rektirino can you try my answer below

Comment: If you are using similar Gary color  #b2000000 then output get gray color use diff. color and check it

Answer (score 1):

Please use this Theme

```
<style name="ThemeFullscreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.translucent_black2));
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
   }
```

Hope this help you...if you need any help you can ask

Comment: No change, same result

Comment: @Rektirino I have used this code for  version 7.0  it's work good

Comment: yes! It turns grey.

Comment: @Rektirino No it's not possible can you see me screen short?

Comment: please show the screen shot

Comment: you show me screen short you have a problem I haven't a problem \

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163473/discussion-between-mahesh-vayak-and-rektirino).

Comment: Shared the output

Comment: try other color and check it

Comment: @MaheshVayak Thank You :) it's working for me.